# cscart orders manage admin table

Tags: cs-cart

I want to add in `orders` table other column with country. Thank you

```
$data = db_get_array('SELECT s_state FROM ?:orders WHERE `order_id`=?i',$key[0]['order_id']);
foreach ($data as $v){
  $country['s_state'] .= (", " . $v['s_state']);
}
```

in `orders.php` backend

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is on the function fn_get_orders to add in the field list the field you want.

The best way to do this is to use the hook `pre_get_orders` to add the field or the hook `get_orders`